# How to initialize the log4j system properly?

Tags: spring, hibernate, log4j

I tried to run sample examples for hibernate and spring but both the time I got below error.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment). 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

I searched over net and added sample log4j file but still problem exists. Could you please help me to resolve my problem as I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

see e.g.:

http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

put the log4j.properties in the classpath.

Comment: I have tried with all these examples but not getting classpath means exactly where. The folder in which java files persist or the folder where .class files persist?

Comment: The folder in which the class files are. If there are only JARs, either add the properties to a JAR or add the folder with the properties to the classpath definition you use in the invocation ot the java executable.

Comment: are you using maven? then put the properties into the directory src/main/resources of your project.